# ASPMVC Attempting to display Dialog to add new item to Combobox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, combobox

I am attempting to follow this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/adding-a-new-category-to-the-dropdownlist-using-jquery-ui
to add a modal dialog to add a new value to a combo box with the modal dialog.  However, I keep getting the following Error:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

My code is as follows:

```
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#genreDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                title: 'Add Genre',
                buttons: {
                    'Save': function () {
                        var createGenreForm = $('#createGenreForm');
                        if (createGenreForm.valid()) {
                            $.post(createGenreForm.attr('action'), createGenreForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                                if (data.Error != '') {
                                    alert(data.Error);
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Add the new genre to the dropdown list and select it
                                    $('#GenreId').append(
                                            $('<option></option>')
                                                .val(data.Genre.GenreId)
                                                .html(data.Genre.Name)
                                                .prop('selected', true)  // Selects the new Genre in the DropDown LB
                                        );
                                    $('#genreDialog').dialog('close');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#genreAddLink').click(function () {
                var createFormUrl = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#genreDialog').html('')
                .load(createFormUrl, function () {
                    // The createGenreForm is loaded on the fly using jQuery load.
                    // In order to have client validation working it is necessary to tell the
                    // jQuery.validator to parse the newly added content
                    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createGenreForm');
                    $('#genreDialog').dialog('open');
                });

                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

My View:

```
@Html.Partial("_ChooseCityDistrict")
```

My PartialView:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityDistrictID, Model.CityDistrictList, "Select Name City District", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

<a class="button" href="@Url.Content("~/NameCityDistricts/Create")" id="genreAddLink">Add New City District</a>

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityDistrictID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })>
```

Any help on getting through this error would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The element `#genreDialog` doesn't exist in your partial view so you code is failing to create your dialog.  Add a `div` with the `id` `genreDialog` to the end of your partial view and it should work -

```
<div id="genreDialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that error says, you're trying to call open method on non existing jquery dialog, so you're missing the hidden div mentioned in the article you've posted

```
<div id="genreDialog" class="hidden"></div>
```